# Resource leak: 'in' is never closed

Tags: java, eclipse, input, resources, memory-leaks

Why does Eclipse give me the warming "Resource leak: 'in' is never closed" in the following code?

```
public void readShapeData() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the width of the Rectangle: ");
        width = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the height of the Rectangle: ");
        height = in.nextDouble();
```

Comment: **To future readers:** many answers state that you must close the scanner, in order to close the underlying resource. While this is true in general, *standard in* is an exception. Closing it will prevent you from reading it again, which is typically undesired. As a rule of thumb: don't close what you didn't open.

Answer (score 100):

Because you don't close your Scanner

```
in.close();
```

Comment: This will close the `Scanner` and silence the warning, but it will also close `System.in` which is typically not desirable.

Comment: @StuartCook +1. Something to keep an eye on.

Comment: Why do we need to close Scanner ? What is meant by "resource leak" ?

Comment: @nogard: this your answer is really helpful.. but when i use in.close();.. again it shows in cannot be resolved.. i have a code without exception handling.. thanks

Comment: @StuartCook, you forgot to mention **why** closing `System.in` is typically not desirable. It's because you won't be able to read from it again. I. e. you will get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` if you try to call `(new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine()` for example.

Comment: All in all, the general recommendation for `System.in` should be NOT to close the wrapping `Scanner` and to add `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` to the enclosing method if you need to make your compiler / Eclipse happy. Or did I overlook something?

Comment: I found this topic very informational helpful keep it up!

Answer (score 71):

As others have said, you need to call 'close' on IO classes.  I'll add that this is an excellent spot to use the try - finally block with no catch, like this:

```
public void readShapeData() throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the width of the Rectangle: ");
        width = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the height of the Rectangle: ");
        height = in.nextDouble();
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

This ensures that your Scanner is always closed, guaranteeing proper resource cleanup.

Equivalently, in Java 7 or greater, you can use the "try-with-resources" syntax:

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    ... 
}
```

Comment: What is meant by resource leak and how will it affect me ?

Comment: @Borat - "resource leak" implies that some system resource (usually memory) is being lost or wasted needlessly.  Usually this will impact you when you start getting OutOfMemoryErrors thrown during the normal operation of your program.

Comment: Thanks eric. I know that you can cause the error by appending a string to itself in an infinite loop. I am not sure how a scanner could cause that error.

Comment: What about a try-with-resources?

Comment: Thanks Dennis, added.

Comment: In the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is a full `try-with`

Comment: This is wrong. You should not close a Scanner that is wrapping System.in.

Answer (score 13):

You need call `in.close()`, in a `finally` block to ensure it occurs.

From the Eclipse documentation, here is *why* it flags this particular problem (**emphasis** mine):

> Classes implementing the interface **java.io.Closeable** (since JDK 1.5)
>   and **java.lang.AutoCloseable** (since JDK 1.7) are considered to
>   represent external resources, which should be closed using method
>   close(), when they are no longer needed.
>
> The Eclipse Java compiler is able to analyze whether code using such
>   types adheres to this policy.
>
> ...
>
> The compiler will flag [violations] with "Resource leak: 'stream' is never closed".

Full explanation [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm&resultof=%22avoiding%22%20%22avoid%22%20%22resource%22%20%22resourc%22%20%22leaks%22%20%22leak%22%20).

Answer (score 7):

It is telling you that you need to close the Scanner you instantiated on `System.in` with `Scanner.close()`. Normally every reader should be closed.

Note that if you close `System.in`, you won't be able to read from it again. You may also take a look at the [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class.

```
public void readShapeData() {
    Console console = System.console();
    double width = Double.parseDouble(console.readLine("Enter the width of the Rectangle: "));
    double height = Double.parseDouble(console.readLine("Enter the height of the Rectangle: "));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that `System.console()` is not available when running an application via Eclipse, which can be a hassle during development.

Answer (score 5):

adding `private static Scanner in;` does not really fix the problem, it only clears out the warning.
Making the scanner static means it remains open forever (or until the class get's unloaded, which nearly is "forever"). 
The compiler gives you no warning any more, since you told him "keep it open forever". But that is not what you really wanted to, since you should close resources as soon as you don't need them any more.

HTH,
Manfred.

Comment: You should not close resources unless you opened those resources.

Answer (score 5):

```
// An InputStream which is typically connected to keyboard input of console programs

Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
```

above line will invoke Constructor of Scanner class with argument System.in, and will return a reference to newly constructed object.

It is connected to a Input Stream that is connected to Keyboard, so now at run-time you can take user input to do required operation.

```
//Write piece of code
```

To remove the memory leak -

```
in.close();//write at end of code.
```

Comment: There is no memory leak and you should not be calling close.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, seriously, in many cases at least, this is actually a bug. It shows up in VS Code as well, and it's the linter noticing that you've reached the end of the enclosing scope without closing the scanner object, but not recognizing that closing all open file descriptors is part of process termination. There's no resource leak because the resources are all cleaned up at termination, and the process goes away, leaving nowhere for the resource to be held.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using JDK7 or 8, you can use try-catch with resources.This will automatically close the scanner.

```
try ( Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); )
  {
    System.out.println("Enter the width of the Rectangle: ");
    width = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the height of the Rectangle: ");
    height = scanner.nextDouble();
  }
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //exception handling...do something (e.g., print the error message)
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Note that the catch clause is not mandatory. If you just want to ensure the resource is closed even in the event of an exception, but leave the treatment of exceptions as in the OP's original code (namely, not caught at all) you can just use `try` as shown and not use a `catch` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You should [close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) your Scanner when you're done with it:

```
in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, instances of classes that deal with I/O should be closed after you're finished with them. So at the end of your code you could add `in.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static Scanner in;
```

I fixed it by declaring in as a private static Scanner class variable. Not sure why that fixed it but that is what eclipse recommended I do.

Comment: you muted the warning but created resource leak

Answer (score -1):

The Scanner should be closed. It is a good practice to close Readers, Streams...and this kind of objects to free up resources and aovid memory leaks; and doing so in a finally block to make sure that they are closed up even if an exception occurs while handling those objects.

Comment: This answer actually helps OP know why he should close the thing. Sure, he can read the doc and see "`scanner.close()`", but this answer really helps him/her understand what's going on. + 1

Answer (score -2):

```
in.close();
scannerObject.close();
```

It will close `Scanner` and shut the warning.