# What does scanner.close() do?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Say I have the following example code:

```
Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);    // declaring new Scanner called scan1
int x = scan1.nextInt();    // scan for user input and set it to x
System.out.println(x);    // print the value of x
scan1.close();    // closes the scanner (I don't know exactly what this does)
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in); // declaring new Scanner called scan1
int y = scan2.nextInt();    // scan for user input and set it to y
System.out.println(y);    // print the value of y
```

I read the [Oracle documentation on the `Scanner` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and came across this:

> When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

Does this mean that once a `Scanner` (of `System.in`) is closed, I will no longer be able to use `System.in` throughout the entire Java program? Or does it mean I will no longer be able to use it throughout the class? Or only the method? Or only its scope?

Another question I have is, is a Scanner restricted to the scope it was declared in (similar to the primitive data types)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close a Scanner linked to System.in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621668/java-closing-scanner-and-resource-leak

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962082/close-scanner-without-closing-system-in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it does mean that `System.in` will be closed. Test case:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CloseScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        scanner.close();
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

This code terminates with

```
$ java CloseScanner 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:206)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at CloseScanner.main(CloseScanner.java:7)
```

Once closed, you won't be able to use `System.in` for the rest of your program. The fact that `close()` is passed through is nice because it means you don't have to maintain a separate reference to the input stream so that you can close it later, for example:

```
scanner = new Scanner(foo.somethingThatMakesAnInputStream());
```

You can do that and call `.close()` on the scanner to close the underlying stream.

In most cases you won't want to close `System.in`, so you won't want to call `.close()` in that case.

Comment: +1 for just trying it with a test case, thereby ducking out of the traps of speculation and theorising.

Comment: The source of Scanner#close http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.close%28%29

Comment: I see, so just to clarify, if I use `scanner.close()` on `System.in` in a for loop in any method (that is called), I won't be able to use it in any of the classes in my program?

Comment: Once it's closed it's closed -- I'm unaware of a way to repoen it, although I don't know that it's impossible (it would certainly be unusual, however)

Comment: Nope, i said that after you closed it you cannot reopen it. Maybe i was not clear.