# What is the difference between closing a resource and making the scanner private in java?

Tags: java

private static Scanner sc;

&

sc.close();

What is the difference between these two things?

Comment: What makes you think those two things are similar?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  "private static Scanner sc;" declares a "Scanner" variable ... but leaves "sc"  uninitialized.  "sc.close();" closes a scanner object.  I havwe no idea what the heck you mean by "&".  IMPORTANT POINT: closing a scanner linked to System.in will close System.in itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142853/close-a-scanner-linked-to-system-in

Answer (score 1):

These two concepts are unrelated. According to the Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245468/what-does-scanner-close-do) thread to learn about `Scanner.close()`.

Comment: you're correct - but it sounds like the OP is deeply confused about more than just "scope" or the "close()" method.

Comment: Fair enough, should I remove this answer or keep it for future visitors?

Comment: Your answer is fine - I'd leave it.  +1 ;)