# Java scanner input loop throwing No Such Element exception after first loop

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I want a program that repeatedly prompts the user to input a number and then prints whether that number is prime or not. This works once, then on the next iteration it gives a No Such Element Exception before the user can enter another input.

I've tried using IF statements with hasNext() or hasNextInt() but those never seem to be true for the same reason. I also tried using a FOR loop to iterate a fixed number of times but that gives the same error. Why is this allowing for user input the first time it loops through but not after that?

```
public static void primeChecker() 
{ 
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
      int number = scan.nextInt();
      if (isPrime(number)) {
        System.out.println(number + " is prime");
      }
      else {
        System.out.println(number + " is not prime");
      }
      scan.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int y=1;
    while(y!=0)
    {
      primeChecker();
}
```

Comment: Don't close your scanner. Otherwise, `System.in` is closed as well and you can't get any user input any more

Comment: What you mean in the "next iteration"? where is it? what does your `primteChecker()` have to do with `y`, which is a local variable of the main method?

Comment: You should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245468/what-does-scanner-close-do

Comment: As presented, the source code as a syntax error. A single iteration through a loop is called a *trip* when not wanting to use *iteration*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `scan.close();`, as it is closing the scanner.

Answer (score -1):

In order to repeatedly ask the user for a number without stopping, you need to put a `while` around the code.

Here is my take on this challenge:

```java
public static void primeChecker() {

    while(true) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        if (isPrime(number)) {
            System.out.println(number + " is prime");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " is not prime");
        }
      
    }      
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    primeChecker();
}
```

This code should repeatedly ask you for a number(after telling you what the previous answer was). It worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

**First of all what does your local variable have to do with the function? even if you pass it to function it won't change.**

by looking at your code one thing you can do is safely remove y it has nothing to with it, and check in prime checker if number is equal to 0 System.exit(), this is one way to do it without changing much of this code.

```
while (true) {
    primeChecker();
}
```

and inside primeChecker

```
int number = scanner.nextInt();
if (number == 0) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

it will terminate the programme when input is 0.

> here you can learn more about System.exit:- https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-exit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).