# Can anybod tell my why java.util.Scanner is throwing this exeption?

Tags: java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FractionTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = scan.nextInt();
        int num2 = scan.nextInt();
        int num3 = scan.nextInt();
        int num4 = scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

This code keeps throwing the error
FractionTester.java: Line 10: java.util.NoSuchElementException
can anybody explain why or how to fix it, please? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java scanner input loop throwing No Such Element exception after first loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67843207/java-scanner-input-loop-throwing-no-such-element-exception-after-first-loop)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are passing 4 input values to the prompt because as its name says NoSuchElementException means scan.nextInt() is not getting any element.
I had tried you code in local and its working for me while passing 4 input values.
see the below code I am giving 4 values to it

[image]

now in here see I am giving only 3 values so it throw the exception
[image]

Comment: Ok thank you for your help with the explanation this is what I was thinking but didn't know how to test it for my self have a great day.

Comment: if you are using CLI then go like this

javac filename.java
then run java FractionTester

and in the console type your values