# Resource Leak (Resource out of scope)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, resource-leak

Hi here are a couple of lines in the code.

```
UserAccountVO fun() {
  // ...
  ObjectInputStream in = xstream.createObjectInputStream(is);
  return (UserAccountVO)in.readObject();
}
```

Now its giving the following warning:

> leaked_resource: Variable *in* going out of scope leaks the resource it refers to".

Can anyone please explain it?

This is how I got it fixed:

```
try(ObjectInputStream in = xstream.createObjectInputStream(is);) {
  return (UserAccountVO)in.readObject();
} catch (IOException e) {
  s_logger.error(e.getMessage());
  return null;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resource leak: 'in' is never closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519335/resource-leak-in-is-never-closed)

Answer (score 2):

In former case, you are not closing the resource 'in' and that may result in memory leak. Therefore you get a warning.
While in later case, you have put the 'in' instantiation within the TRY block which actually adds an implicit 'finally' for you to close the resource.

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I do not need to include finally statement? It gets added automatically. Is it something specific to newer versions  of java? Thanks for the replay :)