# Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java.util.scanner

Program to count how many times a particular character, letter or number occur in a sentence.

However I keep getting message:

> Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed

I am using Java and Eclipse. What should I do?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class Number-count {
    public static void number - count(String args[]) {
        String s;
        char ch;
        int count = 0;
        Scanner SC = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a character to be searched for occurence");
        s = sc.nextLine();
        char c = s.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            ch = str.charAt(i);
            if (ch == c) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Character " + c + " occur " + count + " times");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resource leak: 'in' is never closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519335/resource-leak-in-is-never-closed)

Answer (score 4):

Scanner objects need to be closed after one is done using them. So, after you're done with it you should call the following before the end of your main method

```
SC.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

after your scanner work completed put:  `sc.close();`

It is working 100%

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public static void number - count(String args[]) throws IOException {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   try{
        //your code
      }
   finally {
   sc.close();
   } 
   }
```

Comment: put `.close()` in the `finally` block at the end can avoid resource leak due to any exception happens in the body of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the scanner globally in a class(which is the case sometimes)

*try this:*

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Making it easy for beginners, when we use Scanner sc it is required to be close once we have taken all inputs from user, to close use sc.close(); */

```
package basicjava;
import java.util.*;


public class sumbyuser {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your numbers for summation : ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        int sum = a+b;
        System.out.println("Summation is  : "+sum);
    
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Try sc.close();***

After the using the scanner inputs :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Func1 {

    public static void CalculateSum() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        int sum = a + b;
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculateSum();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The close() somebody already got, the other thing is to change sc. to SC. + I would recommnend main(String[] args), works for me.

```
public static void  main(String[] args) {
    
    String s;
    char ch;
    int count = 0;
    Scanner SC = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
    String str = SC.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter a character to be searched for occurence");
    s = SC.nextLine();
    char c = s.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch == c) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Character " + c + " occur " + count + " times");

    SC.close();
}
```

}